# How to define and use function inside Jenkins Pipeline config?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a task with a function inside:

```
def doCopyMibArtefactsHere(projectName) {
    step ([
        $class: 'CopyArtifact',
        projectName: $projectName,
        filter: '**/**.mib',
        fingerprintArtifacts: true, 
        flatten: true
    ]);
}

def BuildAndCopyMibsHere(projectName, params) {
    build job: $project, parameters: $params
    doCopyMibArtefactsHere($projectName)
}


node { 
    stage('Prepare Mib'){
        BuildAndCopyMibsHere('project1')
    }
}
```

But this gives me an exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'BuildAndCopyMibsHere' found among steps*

**Is there any way to use embedded functions within a Pipeline script?**

Comment: @dr-eel Don't go back and edit the question, especially when an existing answer (see the one from @jon-s) refers to the mistakes in it, as it loses context. I have reverted your change because of this reason only. As for your improvement of using the default parameter `[:]`, suggest that as a comment to the answer from @jon-s or even improve the answer by editing it.

Answer (score 55):

First off, you shouldn't add `$` when you're outside of strings (`$class` in your first function being an exception), so it should be:

```
def doCopyMibArtefactsHere(projectName) {
    step ([
        $class: 'CopyArtifact',
        projectName: projectName,
        filter: '**/**.mib',
        fingerprintArtifacts: true, 
        flatten: true
    ]);
}

def BuildAndCopyMibsHere(projectName, params) {
    build job: project, parameters: params
    doCopyMibArtefactsHere(projectName)
}
...
```

Now, as for your problem; the second function takes two arguments while you're only supplying one argument at the call. Either you have to supply two arguments at the call:

```
...
node { 
    stage('Prepare Mib'){
        BuildAndCopyMibsHere('project1', null)
    }
}
```

... or you need to add a default value to the functions' second argument:

```
def BuildAndCopyMibsHere(projectName, params = null) {
    build job: project, parameters: params
    doCopyMibArtefactsHere($projectName)
}
```

Comment: Ok. Now it says `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: must specify $class with an implementation of interface java.util.List`.
P.S. original code corrected - $ replaced where vars not in strings.

Comment: Strange, seems like a separate issue, try to use the snippet generator to regenerate the copy artefact step. If it still fails, I would suggest posting a new questions as it's a separate issue.